# Recorrer JSON y extraer información

Tags: javascript, json

Me encuentro practicando conocimientos en Javascript, y busco resolver un problema en que me entregan variables con objetos JSON.

La idea es obtener información desde estos objetos y generar un nuevo objeto.

La instrucción es:

> Escribe el código para generar un objeto en que las keys (claves)
> sean los nombres de los depósitos y los valores un arreglo con los
> números de serie de los productos ordenados alfabéticamente por nombre.

```
const storage = [
  { id: 1, name: "Miami" },
  { id: 2, name: "Tampa" },
  { id: 3, name: "Orlando" },
];

const products = [
  { id: 1, SerialNumber: "86620855", name: "Monitor" },
  { id: 2, SerialNumber: "73178559", name: "MotherBoard" },
  { id: 3, SerialNumber: "73826497", name: "Notebook" },
  { id: 4, SerialNumber: "88587715", name: "Consoles" },
  { id: 5, SerialNumber: "94020190", name: "SmartPhones" },
  { id: 6, SerialNumber: "99804238", name: "HeadSets" },
];

const items = [
  { productId: 6, storageId: 1, balance: 150 },
  { productId: 1, storageId: 3, balance: 180 },
  { productId: 5, storageId: 3, balance: 1350 },
  { productId: 2, storageId: 2, balance: 56 },
  { productId: 3, storageId: 1, balance: 230 },
  { productId: 5, storageId: 2, balance: 150 },
  { productId: 3, storageId: 3, balance: 459 },
  { productId: 2, storageId: 3, balance: 190 },
  { productId: 4, storageId: 3, balance: 510 },
  { productId: 5, storageId: 1, balance: 890 },
  { productId: 1, storageId: 2, balance: 16 },
  { productId: 5, storageId: 3, balance: 375 },
  { productId: 6, storageId: 1, balance: 192 },
  { productId: 2, storageId: 3, balance: 100 },
  { productId: 3, storageId: 2, balance: 54 },
  { productId: 3, storageId: 1, balance: 90 },
  { productId: 4, storageId: 3, balance: 135 },
  { productId: 2, storageId: 1, balance: 382 },
  { productId: 5, storageId: 2, balance: 170 },
  { productId: 1, storageId: 3, balance: 10 },
  { productId: 5, storageId: 2, balance: 6 },
  { productId: 6, storageId: 1, balance: 162 },
  { productId: 2, storageId: 2, balance: 100 },
];
```

Hasta ahora he tratado así:

```
const orden = products
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log(orden); // orden alfabeticamente

const miami = storage[0]['name'] //nombres de propiedades
const tampa = storage[1]['name']
const orlando = storage[2]['name']

const arrProduct1 = orden.forEach(function(x){x[x].name}) // busco generar un array de los nombres de productos

const obj = new Object();
obj.miami = arrProduct1;
console.log(obj);
```

Por ahora puedo generar orden según alfabeto de los productos.
Pero no logro extraer información desde los otros objetos.

Comment: Hola Sergio, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Desde mi punto de vista, has avanzado muy poco, por lo que diria que no se nota un esfuerzo de tu parte por solucionar tu problema. Segun entiendo necesitas 1. _"por cada `storage`, buscar en los `items` los productos que pertenecen al mismo"_ 2. _"obtener el número de serie de los productos"_ 3. _"Ordernar los productos en el `storage` en base a su nombre."_. Intenta resolver el punto 1 aunque sea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

todo el proceso puedes hacerlo desde un solo **for**, primero recorre cada uno de los elementos del **storage**, filtra los items por su **storageId** y devuelve el **productId** de **items**(primer map); al tener los **productIds** de cada **storage**, filtramos desde **products**, todos los que coincidan con la lista anterior **productIdList**, estos son los productos del storage, siguiente paso, ordenamos por **nombre(sort)**, y devolvemos los números de series(segundo **map**).Una vez que tengamos el nombre y la lista de números de serie agregamos el **key nombre** con el arreglo de los **números de serie**.

```
var obj = new Object();
storage.forEach(x => {
    const name = x.name;
    const productIdList =  items.filter(y => y.storageId === x.id).map(z => z.productId);
    const serialNumbers = products.filter(p => productIdList.includes(p.id)).sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)).map(q => q.SerialNumber);
    obj[name] = serialNumbers 
});

console.log(obj);
```